# Why does $p(x) = \int d\theta \ p(\theta, x) = \delta(x-X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am reading a probability book and at some point, the following equation comes up:

$$p(x) = \int d\theta \ p(\theta, x) = \delta(x-X) $$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.

Why is this true? I understand the marginalization part over $\theta$ but why is this also equal to $\delta(x-X)$? Isn't the Dirac delta infinity at $x-X$, as opposed to whatever value the density should have?

Comment: What is $p$, and are there bounds on the integral?

Comment: p(x) is the probability of x and the bounds are not given. The full text is available here http://arxiv.org/pdf/0808.0012v1.pdf, the example I mention is on page 42 of the PDF, second line from the top (page 34 of the actual book).

Comment: Don't make us download and search an entire file.  Just give the relevant section.

Comment: They are saying the observed value turned out to be $X$, so the distribution is completely localized at the value of $x=X$. If you integrate the "new" probability function you will get $1$ over any interval containing $X$. Which is what we want